# Showing the result of 2 user-entered variables when clicking a button

Tags: c#, windows, desktop-application

I am new to programming. I'm trying to make a program that stores 2 values that the user enters, and show the result in the 3rd variable => c = 2 ^ (b / a);

Here's what I've tried:

```
public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

public void StepAmount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        a = int.Parse(stepAmount.Text);
    }

    public void StepNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b = int.Parse(stepNo.Text);
    }

    public void DecValue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c = 2 ^ (b / a);
    }

    public void Calculate1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c = int.Parse(decValue.Text);
    }
```

Comment: So how do you want show the result, I don't see anywhere you are doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to release the result when the button is clicked? If so, this must be the code inside the button click event.

```
public void Calculate1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    c = 2 ^ (b / a);
    decValue.Text = c.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that fixed it.